# <video> tag, no sound with Brave and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, video

I try to create a custom video player and averything work with a little video but when I put a video (2H long) there is no sound. I only have this problem with Brave and Chrome
I've try using default  tag with controls but still the same problem

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a Private browsing window and visit the same video link you shared here. Does the video play as intended or do you get the same behavior? If you get the same issue, please try test number two below. If the video works, reply and let me know.
Try disabling Hardware Acceleration in settings to see if this resolves the issue.
You’ll find this in Settings --> Additional Settings --> System --> Hardware Acceleration

[source](https://community.brave.com/t/brave-freezes-when-i-try-to-watch-a-html5-video/198910/6)

Comment: Still don't work, It's really a freeze, only the sound don't work and the icon of the sound is grey and unclickable

Comment: Some code would be useful? Could you possibly post your solution?